# XCTest Completion Handler Assertion Retain Cycle

Tags: xctest, xctestcase, xctestexpectation

I have been writing Xcode tests using the `XCTest` framework for a while, mostly async tests of the getters of a service with completion handlers of the following format with no issues:

```
XCTestExpectation *promise = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Get Something should succeed"];

[self.myService getSomethingOnCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    XCTAssertNil(error, @"Error should be nil");
    [promise fulfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectations:@[promise] timeout:2.0];
```

Suddenly today I go to write my first async setter test of the below format, but get warnings on the `XCTAssert...()` statement within the block saying:

> Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

```
XCTestExpectation *promise = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Set Something should succeed"];

[self.myService setSomething:@"..." onCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    XCTAssertNil(error, @"Error should be nil");
    [promise fulfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectations:@[promise] timeout:2.0];
```

I've even gone to the lengths of commenting out the entire contents of `setSomething: onCompletion:` such that it does not do anything, clean and rebuild, yet the warning still persists.

I do not understand what `self` it is referring to, as the only thing going on inside the block is an `XCTAssert...()` and `[XCTestExpectation fulfill]`. Furthermore, I do not understand why none of the 30+ tests I've written of the first format have no warnings associated with them, but all 5+ I've written of the 2nd format do.

Any explanation on what's going on here and how I can resolve it would be appreciated.

(Using Xcode 10.0)

**Edit 1:**

The issue seems to be with the method name, `setSomething: onCompletion:`. Changing it to anything else, such as `doSomething: onCompletion:` removes the warning. I still don't know how/ why Xcode interprets the `set` command in such a fashion that it presents the warning, so any information would be appreciated.

**Edit 2:**

The following are the method signatures of `setSomething` and `doSomething`:

```
- (void)setSomething:(EnumType)type onCompletion:(SetSomethingCompletionHandler)completion;
- (void)doSomething:(EnumType)type onCompletion:(SetSomethingCompletionHandler)completion
```

Where `SetSomethingCompletionHandler` is defined as :

```
typedef void (^SetSomethingCompletionHandler)(NSError * _Nullable error);
```